# The correct JSON comparison with Strings (SWIFT 3)

Tags: json, xcode, if-statement, swift3

```
    request( url!, method: .get, parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in

            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let newJSON = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(newJSON)
                for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {

                    let age = subJson["age"]
                    let name = subJson["name"]
                    let status = subJson["status"]

  //the code below looks kind of confusing if it gets longer

                    if age == "22"{
                        if status == "highschool "{
                            if name == "Leo"{
                              //do something with the result
```

Is there a better way of checking if the result from JSON is same as the Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic [pyramid of doom](http://www.thomashanning.com/the-pyramid-of-doom/). There are a few ways to get rid of it and you need to pick an appropriate one according to your context. Basically the ways are:

- Using early returns and `guard` statements.
- Combining multiple `if-let` statements into one.
- Using `for-where`.

Given all above you could rewrite your piece of code into something like this:

```
request( url!, method: .get, parameters: nil)
    .responseJSON { response in
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        guard let newJSON = response.result.value else { return }

        let json = JSON(newJSON)

        for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
            let age = subJson["age"]
            let name = subJson["name"]
            let status = subJson["status"]

            if age == "22" && status == "highschool" && name == "Leo" {
                //do something with the result 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Xcode asks me inser `let` before `name age status` . When I do so it then gives me error. **initializer for conditional binding must have optional type**

Comment: @leo0019 seems that `subJson["age"]` is not optional. Then there's no need to do this `guard` dance, just declare those as normal constants. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives:

```
if age == "22" && status == "high school " && name == "Leo" {
```

or

```
switch (age, status, name) {
    case ("22", "high school ", "Leo"): ...
    ...
    default: ...
}
```